# Divisor of two relatively prime

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X=\mathbb{P}^1$, let $f,g\in k[t]$ relatively prime, where $t=X_1/X_2$, two coordinates. Then what can we say $\operatorname{div}(f/g)$? I can just tell that $\operatorname{div}(f/g)=\operatorname{div}(f)-\operatorname{div}(g)$. Is there any further result more than that ?

Comment: What's motivating this question? I'm curious as to why you expect to be able to say more than this? And by the way, the formula ${\rm div}(f/g) = {\rm div}(f) - {\rm div}(g)$ is true even if $f$ and $g$ are not relatively prime: for example, if $f = (t-a)^2(t - b)$ and $g = (t-a)(t - c)$, then $(f) = 2a + b$, $(g) = a + c$ and $(f/g) = a + b - c$.

Comment: @KennyWong This is an exercise in a textbook (Fultons's Algebraic curve). They simply ask to calculate $div(f/g)$ if they are relatively prime. I am not quite sure what is the motivation.

Comment: So yeah, I don't think there's any more to say here...

Comment: You can express it in terms of the zeroes of $f$ and $g$. You should really include the whole problem: the point of this exercise is showing that a principal divisor (on $\mathbb{P}^1$, at least) has degree zero.